# Splitting Column Headers and Duplicating Row Values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, split, co

In the example df below, I'm trying to find a way to split the column headers ('1;2','4','5;6') based on the ';' that exists and duplicate the row values in these split columns.  (My actual df comes from an imported csv file so generally I have around 50-80 column headers that need spliting)

Below is my code below with output

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np  
 #

 data = np.array([['Market','Product Code','1;2','4','5;6'],
            ['Total Customers',123,1,500,400],
            ['Total Customers',123,2,400,320],
            ['Major Customer 1',123,1,100,220],
            ['Major Customer 1',123,2,230,230],
            ['Major Customer 2',123,1,130,30],
            ['Major Customer 2',123,2,20,10],
            ['Total Customers',456,1,500,400],
            ['Total Customers',456,2,400,320],
            ['Major Customer 1',456,1,100,220],
            ['Major Customer 1',456,2,230,230],
            ['Major Customer 2',456,1,130,30],
            ['Major Customer 2',456,2,20,10]])

  df =pd.DataFrame(data)
  df.columns = df.iloc[0]
  df = df.reindex(df.index.drop(0))
  print (df)
0             Market Product Code 1;2    4  5;6
1    Total Customers          123   1  500  400
2    Total Customers          123   2  400  320
3   Major Customer 1          123   1  100  220
4   Major Customer 1          123   2  230  230
5   Major Customer 2          123   1  130   30
6   Major Customer 2          123   2   20   10
7    Total Customers          456   1  500  400
8    Total Customers          456   2  400  320
9   Major Customer 1          456   1  100  220
10  Major Customer 1          456   2  230  230
11  Major Customer 2          456   1  130   30
12  Major Customer 2          456   2   20   10
```

Below is my desired output

```
 0             Market Product Code   1   2      4      5    6
 1    Total Customers          123   1   1     500    400  400
 2    Total Customers          123   2   2     400    320  320
 3   Major Customer 1          123   1   1     100    220  220
 4   Major Customer 1          123   2   2     230    230  230
 5   Major Customer 2          123   1   1     130    30   30
 6   Major Customer 2          123   2   2     20     10   10
 7    Total Customers          456   1   1     500    400  400
 8    Total Customers          456   2   2     400    320  320
 9   Major Customer 1          456   1   1     100    220  220
10  Major Customer 1           456   2   2     230    230  230
11  Major Customer 2           456   1   1     130    30   30
12  Major Customer 2           456   2   2     20     10   10
```

Ideally I would like to perform such a task at the 'read_csv' level. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `reindex` with `repeat`

```
s=df.columns.str.split(';')
df=df.reindex(columns=df.columns.repeat(s.str.len()))
df.columns=sum(s.tolist(),[])
df
Out[247]: 
              Market Product Code  1  2    4    5    6
1    Total Customers          123  1  1  500  400  400
2    Total Customers          123  2  2  400  320  320
3   Major Customer 1          123  1  1  100  220  220
4   Major Customer 1          123  2  2  230  230  230
5   Major Customer 2          123  1  1  130   30   30
6   Major Customer 2          123  2  2   20   10   10
7    Total Customers          456  1  1  500  400  400
8    Total Customers          456  2  2  400  320  320
9   Major Customer 1          456  1  1  100  220  220
10  Major Customer 1          456  2  2  230  230  230
11  Major Customer 2          456  1  1  130   30   30
12  Major Customer 2          456  2  2   20   10   10
```

Comment: Works perfectly @Wen.  Thanks!

Comment: @jwlon81 yw~ :-) happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You can split the columns with ';' and then reconstruct a df:

```
pd.DataFrame({c:df[t] for t in df.columns for c in t.split(';')})
Out[157]: 
    1  2    4    5    6            Market Product Code
1   1  1  500  400  400   Total Customers          123
2   2  2  400  320  320   Total Customers          123
3   1  1  100  220  220  Major Customer 1          123
4   2  2  230  230  230  Major Customer 1          123
5   1  1  130   30   30  Major Customer 2          123
6   2  2   20   10   10  Major Customer 2          123
7   1  1  500  400  400   Total Customers          456
8   2  2  400  320  320   Total Customers          456
9   1  1  100  220  220  Major Customer 1          456
10  2  2  230  230  230  Major Customer 1          456
11  1  1  130   30   30  Major Customer 2          456
12  2  2   20   10   10  Major Customer 2          456
```

Or if you would like to reserve column order:

```
pd.concat([df[t].to_frame(c) for t in df.columns for c in t.split(';')],1)
Out[167]: 
              Market Product Code  1  2    4    5    6
1    Total Customers          123  1  1  500  400  400
2    Total Customers          123  2  2  400  320  320
3   Major Customer 1          123  1  1  100  220  220
4   Major Customer 1          123  2  2  230  230  230
5   Major Customer 2          123  1  1  130   30   30
6   Major Customer 2          123  2  2   20   10   10
7    Total Customers          456  1  1  500  400  400
8    Total Customers          456  2  2  400  320  320
9   Major Customer 1          456  1  1  100  220  220
10  Major Customer 1          456  2  2  230  230  230
11  Major Customer 2          456  1  1  130   30   30
12  Major Customer 2          456  2  2   20   10   10
```